# Lost in Django and jQuery UI autocomplete land

Tags: django, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to learn Django , following a tutorial in an old Django book, and I'm currently stuck on implementing jquery ui autocomplete for a single field in my application.  I've done a lot of searching on this issue only to make myself more confused.  So here's the code in question.

urls.py

```
  `(r'^ajax/tag/autocomplete/$', ajax_tag_autocomplete),`
```

tag_autocomplete.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_tags").autocomplete({
        source: "/ajax/tag/autocomplete/",
    });
});
```

views.py

```
def ajax_tag_autocomplete(request):
    if 'term' in request.GET:
        tags = Tag.objects.filter(
            name__istartswith=request.GET['term']
        )[:10]
        return HttpResponse(u'\n'.join(tag.name for tag in tags))
    return HttpResponse()
```

So when I browse my to my app and start typing characters into this tag field I get nothing displayed, no list is showing up.  However, firebug shows me that the code is performing the query and that it's returning the correct result.  What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: Your script should return JSON array, and as I see it returns tag names separated by '\n'

Comment: Returning a string with the newline separator is how it's supposed to be done for jQuery autocomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Minras said in his comment, your view should return a JSON array of strings or objects to populate the data.

```
from django.utils import simplejson
```

return a json array

```
return HttpResponse( simplejson.dumps( [ tag.name for tag in tags ] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the tags entered into your database? Any results for the following?

```
Tag.objects.all()
```

**Edit:** Actually, instead of using 'term' as your search key, try using 'q'.

Answer (score 0):

czarchaic's answer is correct, but dated.

simplejson is ommitted since Django 1.5

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.5/#django-utils-simplejson

instead of 
from django.utils import simplejson

use 
import json